# how to get the application physical path in windows forms application

Tags: c#, winforms

how to get the application path in windows forms , i used the bellow code but it is saying like "method not found"

```
Application.ExecutablePath;
Application.StartupPath;
```

please suggest me am i missing any namespace ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will return the complete path to your Application

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this as well

```
          System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Answer (score 2):

`System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath` must return the path of the running executable.

Answer (score 1):

Add reference `System.Windows.Forms` and add in using section

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, `Application.StartupPath()` will give the path of the application. And also r u missing this namespace. `System.Windows.Forms`