# In C# how do i get the name of the running file?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly

I would like to know how to pragmatically get the name of the running file not the assembly name but the name of the file in C# .NET,

I tried

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name
```

this  gives the name of the assembly but i am looking for the name of the exe file instead.

Thank you!

Comment: To what end will you use this information? If this is an intermediate step on a solution you've already devised, we may do better knowing what the overall goal is...

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get the application physical path in windows forms application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788881/how-to-get-the-application-physical-path-in-windows-forms-application)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName
```

or

If you want the executable:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
```

If you'd like just the file*name* and not the path, use:

```
Path.GetFileName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
```

Answer (score 2):

System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath

"Gets the path for the executable file that started the application, including the executable name."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you know your assembly is the EXE in which you are running (which I infer is likely, by the use of "GetEntryAssembly()"), you can use Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName. This will return the name of the EXE for your program.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx

Look at the first element in this array.

```
 System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0];
```

You can also look at `args[0]` in `main(string args[])`

This should change even if the program is renamed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```