# c# have sound files in build

Tags: c#, build, uri, pack-uri

I need to make a game for school.

I was adding some sound effects and music.

I have the paths to the .wav in the class and it will play them, but only when I start the game from the bin map in the project. I figgered out that the files are not included inside off the build. I started looking for it but could not find the correct way for it.

I have:

```
MediaPlayer _musicPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
string s = System.IO.Packaging.PackUriHelper.UriSchemePack;
Uri uri = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/{Assembly name};component/Resources/Sounds/Music/Main_theme_-_Thiago_Adamo.wav")
_musicPlayer.Open(uri);
_musicPlayer.Play();
```

This however does not work. If I add an messagebox with:

```
uri.IsFile.ToString()
```

It displays false.

On the file I set the propeties to be:

Build Action: Resource

Copy To Output Directory: Copy Always

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: What are you using `s` for?

Comment: I needed to do that before i could use the "pack://....."
Found that on internet someone else had the same problem.

Comment: Are you doing something other than a basic winforms app? Is it UWP or something like that?

Comment: Have you tried setting the "Build Action" to Resource - you should not need to copy the file as it will be included in the application (at least in WPF).

Comment: It is a Windows Forms App (visual studio -> new project -> 'Windows Forms App (.NET Framework))

Comment: Build action is set to recourse

Comment: Use "Content" instead of "Resource"

Comment: In your uri do you replace "{Application name}" with the actual application name?

Comment: Yes i do replace it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the files to the project in your solution in Visual Studio, so they show up in the Solution Explorer (docked on the right side of the VS window by default). Click on a file so you see the properties window for that file (shown below the Solution Explorer in VS by default). Make sure the `Copy to Output Directory` property is set to either `Copy Always` or `Copy if newer`, and the `Build Action` is set to `Content`. Do this for each sound file you need.

At this point, the files will be copied to same folder as your application when you build it. *They will not be packaged.* They'll just be there in the file system next to your program. If you build the application in Debug mode, this is in the /bin/Debug folder (by default) for your project. If it's Release mode, it's the /bin/Release folder, but as long as your working directory matches your application you can reference them in the Uri by file name alone (otherwise you'll need to [check the application path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788881/how-to-get-the-application-physical-path-in-windows-forms-application) and build the full path to the file).

The reason you need `Content` instead of `Resource` is in the [Remarks section of the `MediaPlayer` class documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6):

> When distributing media with your application, you cannot use a media file as a project resource. In your project file, you must instead set the media type to Content and set CopyToOutputDirectory to PreserveNewest or Always.

Comment: That is the strange part. It does not copy it to that folder. It would be good enough if it did.

Comment: It copies it now. But still not the right path. Do I need to have the 'component' in front of the rest of the path

Comment: I would now expect the URI to simply be the path to your wav file. See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745278/how-to-play-a-sound-file